# Remove listing after being entered

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a website so that it will randomly generate a number. I want to be able to type in the number in a input box, press submit, and have the matching generated number removed from the list.
**I want to only use HTML and Javascript if possible
I tried to look online

Comment: Please put the code you tried to write and the problem of that also.

Comment: I do not know javascript that well. I have not started yet. I am looking for assistance before I start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple implementation is this. You can further develop as you wish.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="result"></div>
      <button type="number" id="get">Get random number</button>
      <div id="arr">
      </div>
      <button type="number" id="rm">Remove number <span id="rnumber"></span></button>
      <script>
      let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
      let n;
      document.getElementById("get").addEventListener("click", getRandomInt);
      document.getElementById("arr").innerHTML = arr;
      document.getElementById("rm").addEventListener("click", rmNumber);

        function getRandomInt() {
        n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = n;
        }
        
        function rmNumber() {
        let n = Number(document.getElementById("result").childNodes[0].textContent);
        arr = arr.filter(i => i != n);
        document.getElementById("arr").innerHTML = arr;
        
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: That looks like it would work. But instead of pressing remove, I want to type the number and press remove to remove that number that I typed. Thanks. Also, I would want to have different sets of numbers. How could I do that?

Comment: If you want to enter the desired number yourself instead of a random number, then you need to add the `input` tag. And in order to add another set of numbers, it is enough to change the value of the `arr` variable.

Comment: I would want it to randomly generate a number, then I could type in a number and have it removed.